# iHaskell: using LaTeX style files in markdown cells

Tags: ihaskell

I know that IHaskell supports LaTeX in markdown cells.  I'd like to include a style file.  How can I do this?  I tried adding an 'include' line to stack.yaml, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this can't be done. For discussion of this, and for alternatives, see https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/issues/752